# showing a map marker at the exact location in css

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I have a database with x and y quadrants and I have a 350x350px map. I have positioned the map as such:

```
background-image: url(/storage/maps/surface.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
height: 350px;
background-position: center center;
margin: 0px auto;
background-size: cover;
```

The width seems to be 429px, not sure why. Im sure it has to do with the `cover`.

On top of this image I have a marker:

```
font-size: 32px;
color: #f9e4b4;
z-index: 5;
position: absolute;
top: 78px;
left: 349px;
```

The `top` represents the Y position and the X position represents the `left`.

These values (`top` and `left`) come from the database and are set in React JS.

This, as it stands creates three divs:

```
<div class="location-map mb-3">
    <div style="background-image: url(&quot;/storage/maps/surface.png&quot;); background-repeat: no-repeat; height: 350px; background-position: center center; margin: 0px auto; background-size: cover;">
        <i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt player-icon" style="top: 78px; left: 349px;"></i>
    </div>
</div>
```

The issue I am having is:

[image]

As you an see, I am trying to position this marker at a pixel perfect position on the map.

now as you see the location states `349, 78` and while this might be right css wise, the marker should be at the edge of the map (on the right) if it was truly 349px's to the left.

**So my question is, is the image too small? did I position the image properly? Why is the marker where it is and not where I want it to be?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two main items to solve:

1. The size of the map element should be an exact `350px` square
2. Using `top` and `left` should place the base of the pin at the **exact** coordinates.

Let's start with the map. If you know the exact image dimensions of your image this should suffice:

```css
.map {
  background: url(http://placehold.it/350x350);
  height: 350px;
  width: 350px;
}
```

```html
<div class="map">
</div>
```

Now lets create the element we want to position using `top` and `left` to the exact pixel, allowing any decoration to fall where it may by using a [pseudo element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements):

```css
.map {
  background: url(http://placehold.it/350x350);
  height: 350px;
  position: relative;
  width: 350px;
}

.map-x-pin {
  background-color: black; /* So we can see where the pixel is */
  height: 1px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 1px;
}

.map-x-pin::after {
  background-color: red; /* Decorative, this could be an image too */
  bottom: 100%;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  left: -10px; /* Half of the width, give or take a pixel */
  position: absolute;
  height: 40px;
  width: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="map">
  <div class="map-x-pin" style="top: 78px; left: 349px;"></div>
</div>
```